# Apache zeppelin response body

Tags: jetty, apache-zeppelin, hdp

how I can change response body for Apache zeppelin?
for example how can change response body **Powered by Jetty.**
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSrvA.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is the response of a server. You can create your own Custom error page and override the server defaults by adding the below configuration in web.xml file

**For 500 server error type,add the below configuration in web.xml**

```
<error-page>
  <error-code>500</error-code>
  <location>Custom error Page path</location>
</error-page>
```

**Reference:** https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/custom-error-pages.html